# newValue always equals to oldValue in AngularJS property watching in unit test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine

I have an controller which is simply watching a 'name' property and prints its new and old values on any change.

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('name', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log('newValue: ' + newValue + ', oldValue: '+ oldValue);
        if (newValue !== oldValue) {
            //...
        }
    }
});
```

Then I want to unit test it with Jasmine:

```
var rootScope, scope, ctrl;
beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
    rootScope = $rootScope;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    ctrl = $controller('Ctrl', { $scope: scope });
}));

it('should have different old and new values if I set a new name', function() {
    rootScope.name = 'some new name';
    rootScope.$apply();

    //expect the behaviors happen for newValue !== oldValue
});
```

Then I expected the console to log a message which is indicating newValue not equals oldValue, however I always get newValue === oldValue. Why the old value is lost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think , this is the behavior. When we 1st time invoke controller, the old value equals to new one and therefore nothing happens. Generally in this case we can write :

```
if(oldValue === newValue){return;}
```

We also can write `$watch` like:

```
$scope.$watch('name', function () {
    // ....
  });
```

and it will be invoked only if `name` is changed:

Demo 1 <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dx6KiNEBfYS41g0Mj6pV?p=preview)</kbd>

I'm not Unitest Guru, anyways try this flow:

**Controller**

```
angular.module('plunker').controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

 $scope.watchFunctionCounter= 0;

  $scope.$watch(function () {
    return $scope.name;
},
function (newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log('newValue: ' + newValue + ', oldValue: '+ oldValue);
        if (newValue !== oldValue) {
            $scope.watchFunctionCounter++;
        }
}, true);
});
```

**Unitest**

```
describe('Directive: maybeLink', function() {
 var scope, ctrl;

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('plunker');

    inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      ctrl = $controller('MyCtrl', {$scope: scope});
    });
  });

  afterEach(function() {
        controller = null;
    });

        it('should have different old and new values if I set a new name', function() {
           scope.name = 'some new name';
           scope.$digest();

          expect(scope.watchFunctionCounter).toBe(0); 
         // on this strage the name is undefined, therefore we stay out of "if" statemant

           scope.name = 'diff name';
           scope.$digest();

          expect(scope.watchFunctionCounter).toBe(1);
     });
});
```

Demo 2 <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pL5VnViDe2VHT9A5QE3i?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: yes as your code demonstrated, what confused me is why the first time you set a new value by `scope.name = 'some new name'` you get `oldValue` equals `newValue` and the counter not incremented? That's my confusion :-(

Answer (score 2):

What I did is to run a digest right after the controller creation, in the beforeEach clause:

```
    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
        rootScope = $rootScope;
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        ctrl = $controller('Ctrl', { $scope: scope });
        scope.$digest();
    }));
```

This way the digest is done before running each test and the watch works correctly.